# Arveson index of a completely positive map on matrix algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Can someone tell me what is Arveson index of a completely positive map. What I want is given a map
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}^m)&\longrightarrow&\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}^n)\\
x&\mapsto &\sum_{j=1}^kv_j^*xv_j,
\end{eqnarray}
what will be the Arveson index of $\psi$?

Comment: What is the definition of this index?

Comment: Norbert, I think the question is about the definition of the index. Not that I know what it is...

Comment: @SKaustav So you are askig for reasonable definition?

Comment: @Norbert yes, and for the finite dimensional case. i shall be obliged if you please provide it.

Comment: @SKaustav I would like to but I don't know even context and motivation of definition. Does there exist definitions of this index for some objects? Why this is excatly Arveson's index not John Smith's for example?

Comment: @Norbert The index was defined by Arveson in http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0129167X99000343 for a completely positive (cp) semigroup. what i wanted was a concept of index for a single cp map, which will follows the spirit of the original one; for example the index should be invariant under unitary transform ($\phi$ and $\phi'=u*\phi(v* ~. ~v)u$ (where $u$ and $v$ are unitaries) should have the same index. I am interested to know whether there is such a definition (for a single cp map), on matrix algebra. (or at least for the contractions/complete  contractions).

Comment: @SKaustav may be [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125597/arveson-index-and-curvature) will help you